# Why are 3-digit hex color code values interpreted differently in Internet EXPLORER?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, colors

How exactly is Internet Explorer interpreting them, and under which guideline or set of standards?

For instance:

`#FFF`

is seem as the color white in Google Chrome, for instance, whereas in Internet Explorer (I tested it on 8 and 9) it appears as black.

I code I used to test this was as follows:

`<body bgcolor="#ffffff">  vs.    <body bgcolor="#fff">`

(I am aware that `bgcolor` is deprecated, it was just convenient for what I was accomplishing at hand).

I am also aware that this is a bug, and that it can be easily fixed by appending a few digits (all-in-all 6) to the hexcode, but I am just interested in seeing the science behind why it occurs, if there is an explanation for it.

Comment: Most likely a bug specifically to do with the deprecated bgcolor, if you apply the #fff through conventional means its fine.

Comment: @Aaron Vanston: The only bug/problem/issue is a developer expecting a predictable uniform result when setting an *invalid value for (HTML's) `bgcolor`* (and then talks about CSS...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to recreate it in IE11 as well. As you know, it is a deprecated attribute. I assume your webpage & the browser are trying to interpret the code as HTML5 and there is a bug in their graceful degradation to handle this. So it just breaks.

As @Aaron Vanston points out, using inline style or CSS, you can still use the shorthand hex to apply a color.

I wouldn't even waste my time writing out `bgcolor` as an attribute. If I came across it in something I was working on, I'd remove it in favor of

```
style="background-color: #fff"
```

or the CSS alternative

```
body {
    background-color: "#fff";
}
```

Answer (score 21):

Since you are *"interested in seeing the science behind why it occurs, if there is an explanation for it"*...

**TLDR:**

'Color-values' are not 'universal'.

The abbreviated/shorthand three-digit hexadecimal `#RGB` form is described in the CSS specification, not in HTML. 
As a result, the three-digit form in an attribute other than "style" or inside a `<style>` tag is not interpreted as a valid color in some browsers.
<sup>https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors</sup>

**In depth:**

I'm starting with the [CSS 1 spec, Color units (6.3)](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS1/#color-units) (as it introduces some terms/concepts I then don't have to repeat), which specifies:

> A color is a either a keyword or a numerical RGB specification.
>
> The suggested list of keyword color names is: aqua, black, blue,
>   fuchsia, gray, green, lime, maroon, navy, olive, purple, red, silver,
>   teal, white, and yellow. These 16 colors are taken from the Windows
>   VGA palette, and their RGB values are not defined in this
>   specification.
>
> ```
> BODY {color: black; background: white }
> H1 { color: maroon }
> H2 { color: olive }
> ```
>
> The RGB color model is being used in numerical color specifications.
>   These examples all specify the same color:
>
> ```
> EM { color: #f00 }              /* #rgb */
> EM { color: #ff0000 }           /* #rrggbb */
> EM { color: rgb(255,0,0) }      /* integer range 0 - 255 */
> EM { color: rgb(100%, 0%, 0%) } /* float range 0.0% - 100.0% */
> ```
>
> The format of an RGB value in hexadecimal notation is a '`#`'
>   immediately followed by either three or six hexadecimal characters.
>   The three-digit RGB notation (`#rgb`) is converted into six-digit form
>   (`#rrggbb`) by replicating digits, not by adding zeros. For example,
>   `#fb0` expands to `#ffbb00`. This makes sure that white (`#ffffff`) can be 
>   specified with the short notation (`#fff`) and removes any dependencies
>   on the color depth of the display.
>
> The format of an RGB value in the functional notation is '`rgb(`'
>   followed by a comma-separated list of three numerical values (either
>   three integer values in the range of 0-255, or three percentage values
>   in the range of 0.0% to 100.0%) followed by '`)`'. Whitespace characters
>   are allowed around the numerical values.
>
> Values outside the numerical ranges should be clipped. The three rules
>   below are therefore equivalent:
>
> ```
> EM { color: rgb(255,0,0) }       /* integer range 0 - 255 */
> EM { color: rgb(300,0,0) }       /* clipped to 255 */
> EM { color: rgb(110%, 0%, 0%) }  /* clipped to 100% */
> ```
>
> RGB colors are specified in the sRGB color space. UAs may vary in the
>   fidelity with which they represent these colors, but use of sRGB
>   provides an unambiguous and objectively measurable definition of what
>   the color should be, which can be related to international standards.

In the context of CSS, with regard to browser-support, the only 2 'interesting' things I could find were:

- *All browsers that support style sheets (version 3 and above, except IE3 Mac) support this three-character shorthand form of hexadecimal colors* <sup>(Sources: [1](http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/hex/), [2](http://style.webreview.com), "Optimize CSS Colors" by King A.B.)</sup>
  Note the historical timeframe of that text.. IE3... on Mac... Browsers like FireFox 1 or Chrome weren't even around back then..
- *The two `rgb()` methods suffer from Internet Explorer 3's non-support for them*
  <sup>Source: [1](http://www.richinstyle.com/masterclass/color.html) (very good read)</sup>

According to the [HTML4 spec, the **attribute**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/index/attributes.html) `bgcolor` was only for `<body>`, `<table>`, `<tr>`, `<th>` and `<td>`. (So as far as the legacy spec is concerned, one can not use it on a `<div>` for example.)

All of them are of the `CDATA`-type: `%Color;`
which was [defined](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/loosedtd.html#Color) as:

```
<!ENTITY % Color "CDATA" -- a color using sRGB: #RRGGBB as Hex values -->

<!-- There are also 16 widely known color names with their sRGB values:

    Black  = #000000    Green  = #008000
    Silver = #C0C0C0    Lime   = #00FF00
    Gray   = #808080    Olive  = #808000
    White  = #FFFFFF    Yellow = #FFFF00
    Maroon = #800000    Navy   = #000080
    Red    = #FF0000    Blue   = #0000FF
    Purple = #800080    Teal   = #008080
    Fuchsia= #FF00FF    Aqua   = #00FFFF
 -->
```

The magic phrase here is: "*a color using [sRGB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB): **#RRGGBB** as Hex values*".

<sup>If I read this wearing a specification-implementor's hat, I must agree that I don't see short-hand 3-digit `#RGB` notation specified and I would not have implemented it (neither would I have implemented `RGB(DDD,DDD,DDD)`).</sup>

As for [HTML5, the `bgcolor` attribute is obsoleted](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html) for all previous (HTML4) specified elements (see above).
That means that, in regard to specification, the format of valid 'color-codes' is not going to change any time soon..

**Conclusion:**

Accepting *only* a named color (from a specified/supported list) or a 'hex triplet' (format `#RRGGBB`) sRGB color-value on the HTML attribute `bgcolor` is not a bug; it is per spec!
Cross-Browser solution: .. see spec ☺

If one mistakingly specifies a short-hand color-value for `bgcolor` on a parsing/rendering engine that doesn't support that, then either nothing happens or a unintended color might show; effectively you have entered ['Chuck Norris'-land](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8318911/588079)..
Most notably for MS IE and MS Outlook, the **colors will seem almost black**. For example: `#ff0` (shorthand) will become `#0f0f00` (instead of `#ffff00`). Another example: `#07c` will become `#00070c`, etc.
*However* some other implementations turn `#ff0` into `#000ff0` and `#07c` into `#00007c`!!
If one mistakingly specifies an `RGB(RRR,GGG,BBB)` value for `bgcolor`, all kinds of colors can appear, for example `RGB(255,255,255)` can become a very dark shade of green <sup>[source](https://litmus.com/blog/background-colors-html-email)</sup>, etc.

So here we have a fun example where Microsoft's Internet Explorer (all known versions, including IE11) *did* follow the spec and a lot of people still complain..
I found countless bug-rapports regarding *"the 3-digit color-value shorthand 'bug' for the `bgcolor`-attribute"* (spanning over 15 years) addressed at for example MS IE, alternative browsers using MS IE HTML parse/rendering engine and the majority of local-app/webbased Email-clients like Gmail, (all versions of) Outlook(-Express), Lotus Notes, Android, etc. etc. etc. <sup>(for example [1](https://www.virtualroi.com/blog/2013/07/the-truth-about-outlook-2013/), [2](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/bluegriffon/nZc4nB_AroQ), [3](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7362589), [4](https://www.sundoginteractive.com/sunblog/posts/help-all-i-see-is-a-black-background-in-my-email), [5](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/forums/topic/7807/gmail-background-color-and-outlook-fontswidths/), etc.)</sup>

*Why the complaints/bug-rapports?*
Because some other browsers (like FireFox, Chrome) **did/do support** color-values in other formats then `#RRGGBB` on HTML's attribute `bgcolor`.
*Why do others support it?*
I have just 2 guesses: (a) It's a leftover from "BrowserWar 1" where one of the battles was around "My browser can make 'sense' of bigger cr@p-code then the competitor's", but somewhat more likely would be (b) reusing the code from the CSS color-value parser... <sup>eventually I would have done that as well</sup>

**Extra:**

*Why would anyone anno 2015 still care about `bgcolor`?*
*Why does that still generate such an amount of bug-rapports and questions?*
The answer is **HTML Email**...
In theory (to the unsuspecting web-developer) it's 'just HTML and CSS'..
In practice it's amazingly hard <sup>([1](http://www.slideshare.net/newzapp/common-email-rendering-issues-a-guide-for-designers))</sup> to get right. Think: all cross-browser issues that ever existed to the power of 3 !
It has to work on *far more* E-mail clients on numerous platforms (loads of 'legacy' applications that are actually still in use), it must also work in web-based clients like Gmail, AOL, Yahoo, Hotmail, etc. etc.
Not only must they code for the lowest common denominator imaginable (much techniques were already considered ancient a fat decade ago), they must even try to 'fit in' with the layout/style of some of the web-based clients.

Their typical structure is one big background table, then one div, then one main table, and nested tables if needed...
To put things into further perspective, according to [litmus](https://litmus.com/community/learning/21-background-colors-in-html-email) (anno 2014):
"*It turns out that the most reliable way of coding background colors is to use the HTML `bgcolor` attribute with a 6-digit hex code on the table and td level*"

Clearly this 'mess' is not going to dis-appear soon and a common thing for a web-developer is to code/design HTML e-mail... Therefore I think that a good complete understanding (and answer to this matter) is still very relevant anno 2015 and the near future.

Hope this helps!

PS: MS IE's `filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient` also doesn't accept 3-digit hex shorthand color values, but now that one is reminded of the notion that 'Color-Values are not Universal', this is less of a surprise (and not a [bug](https://www.drupal.org/node/2113461) unless it was specified that it would accept such values).