# Does Microsoft Edge support short color codes?

Tags: microsoft-edge

Does Microsoft Edge recreate the (broken) behavior of Internet Explorer and display short colors as black - or does it now behave as pretty much any other browser?

Related:

[Why are 3 digit hex color code value interpreted differently in Internet Explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28551981/why-are-3-digit-hex-color-code-values-interpreted-differently-in-internet-explor/32153998)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yep! It works

[image: edge]

That being said, I can only get this to show up using `bgcolor` in any version of IE